# S3 Force File Download with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, header, amazon-s3

I am trying to force files to download from Amazon S3 using the GET request parameter `response-content-disposition`.

I first created a signed URL which works fine when I want to view the file.

I then attempt to redirect there with the `response-content-disposition` header. Here is my code:

```
res.writeHead(302, {
  'response-content-disposition': 'attachment',
  'Location': 'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test/myfile.txt?Expires=1501018110&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXX&Signature=XXXXX',
});
```

However, this just redirects to the file and does not download it.

Also when I try and visit with the file with the `response-content-disposition` as  GET variable:

```
http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test/myfile.txt?Expires=1501018110&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXX&Signature=XXXXX&response-content-disposition=attachment
```

..I reveive the following response:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of using the `response-content-disposition` option is to include it as a GET variable but you're not calculating the signature correctly.

You can find more information on how you should calculate the signature in the [Amazon REST Authentication guide](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can force download a file or can change file name using below sample code. This sample code is to download a file using preSignedUrl.

The important thing here is the ResponseContentDisposition key in params of getSignedUrl method. No need to pass any header in your request like content-disposition ..

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new aws.S3();
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: event.bucket,
        Key: event.key,
        ResponseContentDisposition :'attachment;filename=' + 'myprefix' + event.key
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            context.fail(err);
        }
        else {
            context.succeed(url);
        }
    });
};
```